# Assumption giving convergence of moments

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $\alpha _n\rightarrow \alpha$, then how does one show that for any $j=1,2,\ldots$ and $\epsilon> 0$, if $\sup\int \left | x \right |^{j+\epsilon }d\alpha_n<\infty$, then $\int x^j d\alpha_n \rightarrow \int x^j d\alpha$ as $n \to \infty$?

What if $\epsilon= 0$? Is it still true? For example, if $\sup\int x^2 d\alpha_n<\infty$, then is it necessarily the case that $\int x^2 d\alpha_n\rightarrow \int x^2 d\alpha$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Note:  The above is also posted with an answer on Math Overflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76871/convergence-question

Comment: It is a nice question (+1), but crossposting is not good (-1).

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked and answered [at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76871/convergence-question).

More generally, convergence of the moments under a weak convergence assumption holds under the condition of uniform integrability.